# JOLT transform data create nested pairs

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I am trying to convert the following

```json
[
  {
    "PLCTime": "1643804542000",
    "LevelID": "53.99.2",
    "Data1Type": "Axis1 Dist",
    "Data1": "1.0",
    "Data2Type": "Axis2 Dist",
    "Data2": "2.0",
    "Data3Type": "Axis3 Dist",
    "Data3": "3.0",
    "Data4Type": "Axis4 Dist",
    "Data4": "4.0",
    "Data5Type": "Axis5 Dist",
    "Data5": "5.5",
    "Data6Type": "Axis6 Dist",
    "Data6": "6.0"
/// etc 20 data points
  }
]
```

to achive this as desired output

```json
{
  "assetId": "53.99.2",
  "dataPoints": [
    {
      "timestamp": "1643804542000",
      "measures": [
        {
          "name": "Axis1 Dist",
          "value": 1
        },
        {
          "name": "Axis2 Dist",
          "value": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Where the LevelID becomes "assetID" and PLCTime becomes "timestamp"

So far I have for a spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "LevelID": "LevelID",
        "*": "dataPoints."
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "sort",
    "spec": {
      "*": ""
    }
  }
]
```

which brings the level ID to the top level and gives me and array of data points but from here I am struggling to create pairs from the data below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two successive **shift** transformations in which the attributes with the key names **`Data*Type`** versus **`Data*`** should be seperated first, then combine them back again by their respective indexes of the generated arrays(**`name`** and **`value`**) along with using prefixes in order to generate the desired new array key names(**`measures`**,**`dataPoints`**) such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "Data*Type": {
          "@(0)": "name"
        },
        "Data*": {
          "@(0)": "value"
        },
        "*": "&"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "LevelID": "assetId",
      "PLCTime": "dataPoints[].timestamp",
      "name": {
        "*": {
          "@": "dataPoints[0].measures[&].&2",
          "@(3,value[&])": "dataPoints[0].measures[&].value"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the **demo** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/

[image]